# Unable to remove an item in Firebase using $remove

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I'm trying to perform the simple task of deleting an item from my Firebase database but it's not working no matter what I do. I've been reading the documentation for this [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-remove) and [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-remove) (notice that it's two different remove methods) but none of them works despite my path being correct. It console logs the success message but nothing gets deleted.

So what am I doing wrong exactly?..

```
$scope.deleteAlbum = function(albumToDelete) {

    var ref = new Firebase ('https://exampleurl.firebaseio.com/users/'
                            + $scope.authData.uid
                            + '/albums/' 
                            + albumToDelete
                           );

    var sync = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

        sync.$remove().then(function(ref) {
            console.log('success');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't have `var sync = $firebase(ref).$asObject` when trying to remove something (despite the documentation telling you to do this).

Instead you have to write it like this:

```
var sync = $firebase(ref);
```

And and then call remove on it like `sync.$remove()`. Exactly why this is I have not yet been able to find an answer to so if someone knows do let me know.